# Can I solve pumping lemma for context free language proofs using examples?

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

Say I need to prove that

$L=${$a^n b^n c^n; n\geq 1$} is not context free language

I take n=3.
w=aaabbbccc

Here |w|=9.

we know by pumping lemma-:

|vxy| $\leq$n so vxy=abb

|vy| $\geq$1 so vy=ab

Hence I suppose-:
u=aa
v=a
x=b
y=b
z=bccc

So

$u v^i x y^i z$
=aaaabbbbccc

Hence it is not in L so L is not regular.

But this looks funny to me to be approved in exam. Will it be approved in exam in your opinion? I know it is broad question but there must be CS teachers in cs.stackexchange to know about this? The other proof of this is too hard for me to understand. So I have resorted to this.

Comment: Im not a teacher, but the proof is missing the pumping length. In addition, you cant conclude that $vxy=abb$, since you dont know what $u$ and $z$ are. For the same reason, you dont know what $vy$ is. So I wouldn't approve this proof in an exam.

Comment: I took the pumping length i=2 p robably.

Comment: You cannot choose the pumping length.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x2J5kaf6gjg this guy taught this to me. he chooses i=2. is this guy fraud? i don't think so. he looks legit to me.

Comment: I don't think this guy chooses what the pumping constant is. I see that for every language he wants to disprove using the pumping lemma, he starts with "Exists p pumping constant" in pink.

Comment: @supcem He does not *choose* the pumping constant, he assumes one exists and calls it $p$. This can be done, because every regular and context-free language has a pumping length (proof by contradiction). He then chooses a string from $L$ constructed such that it is at least $p$ symbols in length, and specifically notes that you cannot pick just any short string because it might not be long enough.

Comment: @nirshahar youtube.com/watch?v=9R-vRroo_dE&t=2s this is what I am talking about, is this correct? There is a youtube video, so it can't be wrong I mean he must have seen this somewhere to teach like this. Isn't it?? –

Comment: @supcem he is in fact wrong. Even if its a youtube video, it doesn't automatically imply that he is correct. In the video, he chose the pumping constant to be $6$ - which is not correct. If you could choose the pumping constant, then you could disprove the regularity of $\{1\}\cup \{0\}^*$, which is clearly regular.

Comment: Ok @nirshahar where has it been written that we can't choose pumping length. can you tell me about that? they say there is pumping constant n that depends on L. That is all information we have about pumping constant. Can you tell me why can't we choose pumping constant? Is it because we don't know states of dfa? Or why? Thanks for clarification. Misleading youtubers are everywhere. Half of youtube videos are solved like that way.

Comment: The pumping lemma states roughly: $L$ is regular $\imples \exists p$, which is the pumping length of $L$, such that for all $w$ with length $\ge p$ [...]. So of you want to show that $L$ isn't regular, you need the contra-positive theorem - which negates the quantifiers: $\forall p, \exists w$ such that $|w| \ge p$ and [...], $\implies L$ is not regular

Answer (score 1):

That's an incorrect proof. There are two reasons.

You say that you need to prove that $L$ is a context-free language. The pumping lemma cannot help you with that, since it can only be used to prove that $L$ is not regular (which doesn't imply that $L$ is context free) or that $L$ is not context-free (in its variant for context-free languages).

Assuming instead that you wanted to prove that $L$ is not a regular language, it is not correct to just pick "an example" word.

The pumping lemma statement is as follows:

**Pumping lemma:** if $L$ is regular, then there **exists** some positive integer $p$, such that **for every** word $w$ with $|w|\ge p$, there **exists** a way to write $w$ as $xyz$ with $|xy| \le p$ and $y \ge 1$, such that **for every** integer $i \ge 0$, $xy^iz \in L$.

If you want to show that $L$ is not regular, then you need to prove that the pumping lemma does not hold for $L$. In other words you need to show that the following holds:

**Negation of Pumping Lemma:** **for all** positive integers $p$, there **exists** a word $w$ with $|w|\ge p$ such that, **for every** possible choice of $x,y,z$ with $w=xyz$, $|xy| \le p$, and $|y| \ge 1$, there **exists** an integer $i \ge 0$, such that $xy^iz \not\in L$.

This means that you cannot choose a fixed length of $|w|$. Moreover, you cannot choose the decomposition of $w$ into $x$, $y$, and $z$, but you need to consider all possible decompositions (that satisfy the constraints of the statement above).

Here is a proof that your specific $L$ is not regular by showing that "Negation of Pumping Lemma" holds.

Given **any** value of $p$ (recall that our proof must hold for all $p > 0$), we choose $w=a^p b^p c^p$ and we notice that $|w| = 3p \ge p$. We are allowed choose $w$ since we only need to show that a suitable word $w$ **exists**.

We now consider **all possible** ways of writing $w$ as $xyz$ with $|xy|\le p$ and $|y| \ge 1$. Notice that $xy$ must contains only $a$s, therefore $x$ must be of the form $a^j$ for some $j \ge 0$, $y$ must be of the form $a^h$ for some $h \ge 1$, $j+h \le p$, and $z$ is of the form $a^{p-j-h}b^p c^p$.

Next, we pick a value for $i$ (a single value suffices since we only need to show that a suitable value **exists**). In particular we choose $i=0$.

We need to verify that $x y^i z \not\in L$. This is true since:
$$
x y^i z = a^j (a^h)^i a^{p-j-h}b^p c^p = a^{p-h}b^p c^p,
$$
and $h \ge 1$.

This shows that "Negation of Pumping Lemma" holds for $L$, i.e., that the Pumping Lemma fails for $L$. As a consequence $L$ cannot be regular. This concludes the proof.

Comment: this is for context free language. i rewrote the question. it is bit tougher to solve like that in case of context free language so I resorted to that way. Is there some simpler way of this proof in CFL? I can do proofs for RL I used easy theory youtube channel explanations for that. But his explanations for CFL aren't easy to follow.

Comment: can you share some resources for me to get through pumping lemma proofs, it seems very confusing to me. any easy proofs techniques. i loved easy theory videos of pumping lemma for regular language. but his videos for cfl aren't my cup of tea. any resources please recommend.

Comment: You could have a look at chapters 4 (for regular languages) and 7 (for context-free languages) of the book "Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation" by Hopcroft et al.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9R-vRroo_dE&t=2s
this is what I am talking about, is this correct? There is a youtube video, so it can't be wrong I mean he must have seen this somewhere to teach like this. Isn't it??

Comment: The youtube video is wrong. Specifically, it is wrong at minute 6 when they pick $c=6$. Unfortunately (?), the fact that something is an a youtube video doesn't mean that it must be right...

Answer (score 1):

There are very many flaws in this proof attempt, and I would not give marks for this.

First of all: $L$ is NOT context-free and the pumping lemma for context-free languages can only be used to prove that a language is NOT context-free. Similar to the better-known pumping lemma for regular languages, there are non-context free languages that have the pumping properties required by the lemma.

Second: the pumping properties rely on the assumption that there exists a finite pumping length $p$, and that only strings containing $p$ or more symbols are subject to the requirements of the lemma. Therefore, you can't use the string $aaabbbccc$, because it's possible $p > 9$ for all possible pumping lengths $p$ of $L$ in which case we wouldn't expect the conditions to hold anyway. You can use any $s \in L$ with $|s| \geq p$, for instance $a^pb^pc^p$.

Third: after you have fixed the string for observation, eg. $s = a^pb^pc^p$ as above you must present the $uvxyz$ division under the conditions given is impossible to satisfy. You have to show that *every* choice of $uvxyz$ fails at least one of the lemma's conditions. The choice of $s$ here matters a lot: as the "center part" of the string is bounded in length – more formally, $|vxy| \leq p$, you know that $v$ and $y$ contain no $a$ symbols, no $c$ symbols, or neither symbol, which gets you the expected result of $L$ being non-context free.

Try again with these notes in mind, and I think you will have an easier time.

Comment: My logic is that if it fails for 1 example, then it is not CFL. Why is this logic wrong? Can you explain?

Comment: What do you mean by "failing one example"? **What** failed? You applied the pumping lemma in a wrong way so this one example doesnt imply anything.

Comment: @nirshahar i am really confused in applying pumping lemma specially for cfl, can you guide me a simpler approach which is more initutitive? i watched easy theory youtube video but could not clarify this pumping lemma for cfl. i got for regular language tho. but since he uses different method that was of no use really. they say this contains only a's....this contain only bs...I don't get it. what they are trying to do. please guide

Comment: @supcem I recommend you start by learning the simpler pumping lemma for regular languages. The two main mistakes you make here – those being the wrong choice of string (too short) and showing only one non-satisfying $uvxyz$ partition of the string (instead of demonstrating that *no* satisfying partition exists) – are the kind you could work on understanding with the pumping lemma for regular languages, where you have to make the choice of the string and the proof of impossibility of a satisfying partitioning in a similar manner.

Comment: I don't see any resources to learn bro. I have 5 textbooks but I can't understand from any of them. Do you have some resources that you used for learning @kviiri. I watched easy theory video for regular language and that messed things up. he taught it so easily but in a different way and taught cfl pumping lemma in different way that i can't comprehend.

Comment: If you understand the pumping lemma for regular languages, you just need to apply the same concepts to your proof above. In both pumping lemmas, you need to choose a string of at least length $p$, and you need to demonstrate that no partition that meets all three criteria exists. The set of criteria is a bit different and more complex for context-free languages, but the basic premise is the same. Sadly I don't have any resources to recommend, it's been years since i learned this stuff.

Comment: @kviiri https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9R-vRroo_dE&t=2s
 this is exactly what I am talking about. can I do this? I found a video which did exactly what I did.

Comment: @supcem That video is sadly wrong in many places. For one, the author slips up at several locations and claims the finite pumping property proves a language to regular (only the converse works), the pumping length $c$ (or $p$ as we often call it) should not be fixed to a particular value (just assumed to exist) and doesn't prove that the $xyz$ division is impossible, just presents examples of divisions that do not work.

Comment: thanks for clarification. self learning is really tough with these kind of dudes everywhere. @kviiri

Comment: @supcem I don't know of any videos but it just occured to me that I wrote a fairly comprehensive example of pumping lemma on Math.SE a few years back, I hope it helps you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/963969/prove-that-the-set-of-palindromes-are-not-regular-languages-using-the-pumping-le/991976#991976

Here we show the language of palindromes is not a regular language. Note in particular how we assume $p$ exists but do not set its value: this way the proof is general. The choice of the string leaves us only a fairly limited set of $xyz$ divisions to explore.